# How to edit a row in Material UI Table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I trying to make a crud table using material UI,but as my first react project I have some issues.I don't know how to make the edit.I take the data to the edit-modal but I don't know how to make the update in the table.

```
export default function ResponsiveDialog({dataParent1,dataParent2}) {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const theme = useTheme();
  const fullScreen = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('md'));

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button variant="outlined" color='success' onClick={handleClickOpen}>
        Edit
      </Button>
      <Dialog
        fullScreen={fullScreen}
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="responsive-dialog-title"
      >
        <DialogTitle id="responsive-dialog-title">{"Edit Post"}
        </DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
        <Divider variant="middle"/>
          <DialogContentText>
            Title
          </DialogContentText>
          <TextField id="outlined-basic" defaultValue={dataParent1} style = {{width: 500}} variant="outlined" />
          <DialogContentText>
            Description
          </DialogContentText>
          <TextField id="outlined-basic" multiline rows={4} defaultValue={dataParent2}  style = {{width: 500}} variant="outlined" />
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button autoFocus variant="outlined" color='error' onClick={handleClose}>
            Exit
          </Button>
          <Button color='success' variant="outlined" onClick={handleClose} autoFocus>
            Save Changes
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );}
```

Codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-panka-7wd7ye?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Add the appropriate code here as a minimal reproducible example using the snippet tool [<>] in the edit toolbar

Comment: I don't know how to do that, but I can send to you the Github link:https://github.com/harli-lacej/practical-react-app

Comment: Hello @MohitSharma,I added the code sand box link in the post.Thank you!